# Populating an NSBrowser (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsbrowser

I want to make a widget that displays a column of selectable text data.  It seems that the NSBrowser is the best cocoa object to do this but I cannot figure out how to populate the NSBrowser with any sort of data.  I assume I can set the string value of an NsBrowserCell but no where in the documentation can I find where to add a new cell to a column.  Am I using the wrong object?

Comment: “I want to make a widget that displays a column of selectable text data. It seems that the NSBrowser is the best cocoa object to do this …”

Probably not. NSBrowser is for browsing hierarchies, like the file-system. You may recognize it as the Column View in Finder, Transmit, and a few other applications. An NSTableView may work better for what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One must define a NSBrowserDelegate and define both `‑browser:willDisplayCell:atRow:column:` and `‑browser:numberOfRowsInColumn:` or the method `‑browser:createRowsForColumn:inMatrix:`.  This link is useful:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/31229-nsbrowser-question.html